# Do Firefox Persona slow your computer?

Tags: firefox, performance

I have noticed that my system has slowed down since i started using Firefox Persona. it is very frustrating to move to next tab. Is it because of the Personas or is my computer to be blamed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can't tell until you play around with Firefox for at least a few hours *without* a Persona first, can't we? (Even in computers there are controlled experiments.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they shouldn't slow you down too much if at all. You'd be better off looking in to extensions and crapware on your machine.

I run an aero skin for Firefox and I don't notice any speed difference from stock (it could however affect yours, it all depends on hardware, and software setups)